# Bug in thereIsSimilarID function causing unexpected return value (24)

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I apologize for the lengthy code, but I'm encountering an unexpected issue in my C++ program. I have a vector (`teamNum`) of a class type that contains a vector (`player`) of a struct type. In the `thereIsSimilarID` function, I aim to check if there exists a player in `teamNum` with the following conditions: `tName` equal to `_tname` (function parameter) and `pID` equal to `_pID` (function parameter).

```cpp
bool thereIsSimilarID(string _tname, int _pID)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < teamNum.size(); i++)
    {
        if (teamNum[i].tName == _tname)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < teamNum[i].player.size(); j++)
            {
                if (teamNum[i].player[j].pID == _pID)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        else if (i == (teamNum.size() - 1))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `main` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "\n" << thereIsSimilarID("Leverpool", 1) << endl;
}
```

The unexpected output is 24, and this issue only occurs when the team ("Leverpool") is the last team in the `teamNum` vector.

I'd appreciate any guidance on identifying and resolving this bug. Additionally, if possible, please help me understand the root cause so that I can learn from the solution. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: [Off Topic] Get rid of `else if (i == (teamNum.size() - 1))
    {
        return false;
    }` and just put `return false;` after the for loop.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: What if `teamNum.size() == 0`?  That entire `for` loop is skipped, and the value returned is ---  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.  Actually, the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you that there are code path that don't lead to a `return` statement. The return value is *unspecified* in those paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered undefined behaviour.

If you take the `if (teamNum[i].tName == _tname)`-branch on the last element, but find no player with the correct pID, you don't return anything. Which means, that the return value is whatever random value is currently in the memory location that should hold the return value. In your case it happens to 24. But theoretically, everything could happen.

The same problem occurs when `teamNum` is empty.

The solution is to make sure to always return a value from a function (except if it has return type `void` of course):

```
bool thereIsSimilarID(string _tname, int _pID)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < teamNum.size(); i++)
    {
        // In this loop return true if you find a matching element
    }

    // If no matching element was found we reach this point and make sure to return a value
    return false;
}
```

---

You should take a look at your compiler settings and enable all the warnings. And often it's good to let it treat certain warnings as errors.